# Angular Material datepicker lazy load

Tags: angular

I've got an Angular application with multiple modules which are lazily loaded. However, when I broke my app into these modules my `this.adapter.setLocale(locale);` in main module stopped working. **Is there a way to populate this change across modules except for manually setting locale in each module on init?**

So I may have different locales set to `this.adapter.setLocale()` and that doesn't seem to make any difference on a datepicker (it still uses 'uk').
 When there were no modules with lazy load it worked well.

I have a shared module for Material, which I import in other modules then.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {
    MAT_DATE_LOCALE,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatSelectModule
} from "@angular/material";
import { MatMomentDateModule } from "@angular/material-moment-adapter";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MatInputModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatMomentDateModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatAutocompleteModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
    ],
    providers: [
        {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'uk'},
    ],
    exports: [
        MatInputModule,
        MatDatepickerModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatMomentDateModule,
        MatSelectModule,
        MatAutocompleteModule,
        MatCheckboxModule,
    ]
})
export class MaterialModule {
}
```

---

In other words I want my entire app to use the same locale in Material Datepicker across different feature modules.

Comment: Same problem here. I tried using a `ModuleWithProviders` sharing the properties accross lazy modules without success

Answer (score 3):

Ok it's working now. You have to use `ModuleWithProviders`

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE, DateAdapter, NativeDateAdapter, MatDateFormats } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { Platform } from '@angular/cdk/platform';

import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeDe from '@angular/common/locales/de';
import localeDeExtra from '@angular/common/locales/extra/de';

registerLocaleData(localeDe, 'de-De', localeDeExtra);

export const MY_FORMATS: MatDateFormats = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit'}
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit'},
    monthYearLabel: {year: 'numeric', month: 'short'},
    dateA11yLabel: {year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric'},
    monthYearA11yLabel: {year: 'numeric', month: 'long'}
  },
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatDatepickerModule
  ],
  exports: [
    MatDatepickerModule
  ]
})
export class SharedModule {
  static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: SharedModule,
      providers: [
        { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'de-DE' },
        { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: NativeDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, Platform] },
        { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

And then use the SharedModule in your AppModule like

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    SharedModule.forRoot()
  ]

  ...
```

Comment: What about your comment? What's changed? I've also tried this approach but it didn't succeed

Comment: Switching Core to provide a forRoot worked for me. You need to use the Generic version with the latest version now though. For example: ModuleWithProviders<CoreModule>

Comment: not mentioned in the answer, it is needed to import the SharedModule at the lazy modules, without the `forRoot`, of course.